# Append html to a QWebView?

Tags: qt

I've got a `webView` setup to display chat message.

I'm initiating it like this:

```
ui->webView->setHtml("<html style=\"font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size:13px;\">
                     <head></head>
                     <body style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\"> 
                     <div id=\"date\"style=\"position:fixed;top:0;height:40px;background-color:#ffffff;opacity:0.9;width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;\"><span style=\"display:block;color:#6d7382;padding-top:12px;padding-left:14px;\">friday</span></div>  
                     <div style=\"padding:12px;background-color:#f5f5f5;display:block;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;border-top:1px solid #f1f1f1;\"><div style=\"color:#606775;font-weight:bold;\">Bill</div><div style=\"color:#5a5a5a;\"><p>Hello</p></div></div>   
                     </body></html>");
```

*(The above code is all on one line in QT, I just hit enter to make it easier to read here)*

Now I'm trying to figure out how to append `div's` it to in the form of new chat messages.

Tried to append like this:

```
QString html = "<div>Test test</div>";
QString js = QString("document.execCommand('InsertHTML',false,'%1');").arg(html);
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(js);
```

Switching out the date works fine, I do that like this:

```
// Switches out the date
QWebFrame *pSource = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame();
QWebElement dateDiv = pSource->findFirstElement("#date");
dateDiv.replace("<div id=\"date\"style=\"position:fixed;top:0;height:40px;background-color:#ffffff;opacity:0.9;width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;\"><span style=\"display:block;color:#6d7382;padding-top:12px;padding-left:14px;\">sunday</span></div>");
```

However inserting new `div's` is what i cannot get to work.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This added the given div to QWebView for me:

```
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().appendInside(html);
```

btw. long lines of html u can split just like that:

```
    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->setHtml("<html style=\"font-family:Lucida Grande;font-size:13px;\">" \
                     "<head></head>" \
                     "<body style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\">" \
                     "<div id=\"date\"style=\"position:fixed;top:0;height:40px;background-color:#ffffff;opacity:0.9;width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;\"><span style=\"display:block;color:#6d7382;padding-top:12px;padding-left:14px;\">friday</span></div>" \
                     "<div style=\"padding:12px;background-color:#f5f5f5;display:block;border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;border-top:1px solid #f1f1f1;\"><div style=\"color:#606775;font-weight:bold;\">Bill</div><div style=\"color:#5a5a5a;\"><p>Hello</p></div></div>" \
                     "</body></html>");
```

Comment: That works, but it insides outside of the `body` tag, can i somehow make that get inserted into the body tag?